# bootstrap "required" form validation pop-over doesn't work on ipad (safari or chrome)

Tags: ios, ipad, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap, validation

This markup works fine on desktop browsers

```
<form class="form-inline" action="/action/sign-me-up" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
<input type="email" placeholder="Email" class='email' required title="Join our email list">
</form>
```

If I submit the form without a valid email in the input[type=email] I get a pop-over that says "Please fill out this field" and the form does not submit.

However, on the ipad, I do get the live validation (red border) while the user is entering an email, but I do NOT get the popover if they hit submit.

Is there an easy workaround, or do I need to use a jquery plugin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The message is a browser default triggered by the HTML5 'required' attribute. Unfortunately iOS and indeed a bunch of other browsers don't yet support it.

http://caniuse.com/form-validation

We've just had this very same issue which we solved with the Webshims library - http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/  which is written in jQuery and is built on top of Modernizr.